# How can we verify Elasticsearch document if we enable store:no for that field

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set `store:no` for a field in my elasticsearch document. But `source` is enabled. 
When we search data over `store:no` field it will display records on behalf of that fields in search result but that field will not display in source ( as we have set `store:no`).

So my question Is there any way to cross verify that document in Elasticsearch have document has `store:no` field in it?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you set the value of `store` to `no` that field **will** be kept in the `_source` field (unless you disable that field, too) so it should be returned to you.

But if you want to only query documents that actually contain a specific value you can use the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html). Even with `store:no` you can do:

```
{
    "exists" : { "field" : "value" }
}
```

Comment: Its showing me search result on behalf of `exists` filter But its now showing that field in search result.

Comment: @Roopendra can you show your search query? It should return the `_source` field by default

Comment: @Roopendra yes with that query in results you should have a `_source` field in `hits/hits`, that document should contain all the fields, including `field`, what's the problem?

Comment: Yeah I know field listed in _source under hits/hits. But its not displaying for me.

Comment: @Roopendra what do you mean its not displayed? Not displayed in `_source` or not displayed in the `hits/hits`? Could you update your question with the actual response?